# Take cell value from a cell containing a function/formula

Tags: excel

[image]

From the picture, I want to find the distance traveled. 
My formula @ cell O83 looks something like : =$M83- $M82. But O83 returns Zero. 
Note: column M82 contains a formula. 
Question: how do I extract and use just the value from a function?

Comment: Can you post the formula in M82 and M83.  The formula you provide should be picking up the value.

Comment: Even if it's a formula you should see 14.3 in O83 , check if you have formatted O83 to something which is probably the reason for this.

Comment: Is your sheet set to calculate automatically?

Comment: @urdearboy yes.

Comment: @ImranMalek how do I do that?

Comment: I would check with @ImranMalek comment then. If the sheet is calculating automatically, i'm guessing you have a format that is hiding the true value. Change the format to `General`, do you get a number?

Comment: @VOM just apply general format to the cell.

Comment: @Imran: it is in General format

Comment: Put some values in column P like 1 in P82 and 1 in P83 and write a simple formula in P84=P83+P82 ,do you get result there  ? Also have applied any formats to column M ?

Comment: @ImranMalek yes

Comment: Use the format painter from `P84` and copy the format to your issue cell (`O83`). How about now?

Comment: it works now. But how do I extract a value from a cell containing a formula?

Comment: What is the formula in those cells.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the formatting that you might have applied on the cell O82

See the example below 
[image]

If you remove the formats on the problematic cells you'll see the correct results.
[image]

To do so select all the range O82:O100 and click on clear formats from home tab.

[image]